# Clarification of proof of a theorem about complex-antilinear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

There is a statement about complex-antilinear operator.

I have a sketch of a proof, but some things are not clear.

> **Statement**
>
> Given $\sigma $ - complex antilinear operator $V_R \to V_R$ such that $\sigma^2 = id$. Then $V = \mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} W$ , where $W = Ker(\sigma - id)$.

First of all, if I have an arbitrary operator $\sigma$ (not necessarily antilinear) what elements lie in $Ker(\sigma - id)$?(1)

**Proof**

We start by considering reification of $V$, namely $V_\mathbb{R}$.

$V_\mathbb{R} = Ker\left(\sigma^2 - id\right)$. Here I understand that $\sigma^2 - id$ is a null operator, but who do we conclude that $V_\mathbb{R}$ equals to kernel of a null operator?(2)

Then we proceeded with $Ker\left(\sigma^2 - id\right) = Ker\left(\sigma - id\right) \oplus Ker\left(\sigma + id\right)$. I guess that is by some theorem which states if we have a polynomial that can be factored on some irreducible polynomials than its kernel can be factored in direct sum of kernels of that irreducible polynomials, right?(3)

After we are using a property of complex-antilinear operator $\sigma(iv) = -i\sigma(v)$ and from that we deduce that multiplication by $i$ gives us an isomorphism between $Ker\left(\sigma - id\right)$ and $Ker\left(\sigma + id\right)$. How do we see that multplication by $i$ is an isomorphism?(4)

Finally, we check what we get if we multiply by complex number:

$(a + ib)(v + iw) = (av - bw) + i(bv + aw)$ and deduce that $V = \mathbb{C} \otimes W$, $W = Ker(\sigma - id)$.(5)

This final step looks completely unclear to me. Why we want to check the result of $(a + ib)(v + iw) = (av - bw) + i(bv + aw)$ and how do we deduce the final results?

It would be nice if someone could clarify to me at least some steps marked by (1), (2), (3), (4), (5).